# Can I Query by Key in an App Engine Projection Query?

Tags: python-2.7, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

tldr: Can I do this in a Datastore projection query?

```
keyProjectionQuery = Conferences.query(       \
    key=ndb.Key(Conferences, RegistrationId), \
    projection=[Conferences.allConferences])
```

In detail:
Consider the following, where Students entity is an ancestor of Conferences entity.

- There is only one entity in Conferences kind for every student in Students kind.
- Conferences.allConferences holds every conference that a student has attended as a repeated field.

  class Students(ndb.model):

  ```
  RegistrationId      = ndb.StringProperty()
  Name                = ndb.StringProperty()
  ```

  class Conferences(ndb.model):

  ```
  allConferences = ndb.StringProperty(repeated=True)
  ```

  class StudentsForm(messages.message):

  ```
  Name                = messages.StringField(1)
  RegistrationId      = messages.StringField(2)
  ```

  class ConferencesForm(messages.message):

  ```
  allConferences = messages.StringField(1, repeated=True)
  ```

I have a projection query that gets Conferences.allConferences based on ancestor key:-

```
ancestorProjQuery = Conferences.query(          \
    ancestor=ndb.Key(Students, RegistrationId), \
    projection=[Conferences.allConferences])
```

Can I use Conferences key in a projection query? Something like this?

```
keyProjQuery = Conferences.query(             \
    key=ndb.Key(Conferences, RegistrationId), \
    projection=[Conferences.allConferences])
```

I tried it, but I get an error:

```
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'key'
```

The third option is ofcourse to get the entire entity from Conferences and return only the allConferences property.

```
AllConferences = ndb.Key(Conferences, RegistrationId).get()
```

Also, which of these will be cheaper?

I am very new to Python, Datastore and App Engine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
Conferences.query(
    Conferences.key==ndb.Key(Conferences, RegistrationId), projection=["allConferences"]
)
```

Comment: That worked like a charm! thank you! Any pointers about the datastore cost?

Comment: A tiny addition. I had to add parent key to get this to work: 

`query = Conferences.query( Conferences.key== ndb.Key(Conferences, RegistrationId, parent=ndb.Key(Student, RegistrationId)),projection=["allConferences"])`